# Jquery not populating the html table

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, pagination, paging

I have implemented paging in MVC and using JQUERY to populate the table.
But i don't know why jquery is not populating the result.

My Controller Method:

```
 public ActionResult Clear()
        {
            IPagedList<Provider> providerList = null;
        providerList=db.Provider.OrderBy(x=>x.ProviderName).ToPagedList(1,100);
            return Json(providerList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
       }
```

My Jquery:

```
 $('#clearSearchButton').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Content("~/Provider/Clear")',
            type: "GET",
            //  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "json",
            sucess: function (data) {
                alert("You are in success function");
                // $("tbody").empty();
                $.each(function (index, value) {
                    $('#tblData').append("<tr><td style='text-align: center;'><input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' name='deleteIds' value=" + value.Id
                        + "></td><td>" + value.ProviderName
                        + "</td><td>" + value.LegalProviderName
                        + "</td><td>" + value.Email
                        + "</td><td>" + value.HotLineNumber
                        + "</td><td><a href=" + value.WebSiteLink + " target='_blank'>" + value.WebSiteLink + "</a>"
                        + "</td><td><a href=" + value.AdminPortalLink + " target='_blank'>" + value.AdminPortalLink + "</a>"
                        + "</td><td> <a href=Provider/Details/" + value.Id
                        + ">Details</a> | <a href=Provider/Edit/" + value.Id
                        + ">Edit</a> | <a href=Provider/Delete/" + value.Id
                        + ">Delete</a> |  <a href=ProviderDocument/" + value.Id + " target='_blank'>Doc</a>"
                        + "</td></tr>");
                })
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('error');
            }



        });
    });
```

Please help me how can I populate my data.

Comment: `$.each(data, function(...)....)`  [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

Comment: Not working out for me

Comment: Check if the data in success callback is correct or not.

Comment: How can I do that? I am very at this.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in developer tool or `console.log(data)`

Comment: alright I tried that but developer tool's debugger is saying that it "can't put a debugger as one is already attached" although I have removed all the debuggers from my code in Visual Studio

Comment: my success function is not executing

Comment: `sucess: function (data)` a typo here at `success`

Comment: is it because of the unusal space I left between function and (data)  ??

Comment: Thanks alot got my mistake i wrote the word success wrong. Thanks alot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify that your response is success, 
console log to your data output structure. if it is as expected, use the $.each method as below,

```
$.each(function (index, value) { ... }
```

To:

```
 $.each(data, function (index, value) { ... }
```

Comment: i tried your way but it still is not doing anything

Comment: my success function is not executing